# Implement the Function.prototype.apply function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I do not care much about the context and I do not want to use Function(). The function should take a function and an array of parameters. Example

```
apply(fn, args) => fn(args[0], args[1], ..., args[args.length-1]);
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: You have such odd restrictions.  Is this homework?

Comment: None, a friend asked me and I found it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
var apply = function(fn, args) {
  var _fn = fn;
  args.forEach(function(arg) {
    _fn = _fn.bind(null, arg);
  });
  return _fn();
};

apply(
  function() { console.log(arguments); },
  [ 'arg 1', 'arg 2', 'arg 3', 'arg 4' ]
);
```

Comment: Creative, but certainly not very efficient as you end up with a function call for every argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 _obviously_ not very efficient, but efficiency wasn't part of the brief :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of args then this is the only way:

```
function apply(fn, args) {
    return fn.apply(null, args);
}
```

if you know the number (say 2):

```
function apply(fn, args) {
    return fn(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

Or:

```
function apply(fn, args) {

    switch (args.length) {
        case 0:
            return fn();
        case 1:
            return fn(args[0]);
        case 2:
            return fn(args[0], args[1]);
        case 3:
            return fn(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use the apply function, since I am trying to implement it :)

Comment: You're not going to be able to then unless you know the number of arguments

Comment: So there is no general solution to this?

Comment: @jfriend00, args here is the array passed in not the built in arguments array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nasty solution using eval:

```
function apply(fn, args) {

    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        a.push("args["+i+"]");
    }

    command_string = "function inner_apply(fn, args) { return fn(" + a.join(",") + ");} ";

    eval(command_string);
    return inner_apply(fn, args);
    }
```

Please never use this is real life!

Comment: As I mention, I do not want to Function() which is kind of similar what eval() can do for us.

Comment: Without these there is no way. Why do you need this for?